# Group by and having with where together?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in place...

```
        ID      awaiting    approve decline      
        100       1         0         0     
        100       0         0         1     
        102       1         0         0     
        103       0         1         0     
        104       0         1         0     
        104       0         1         0     
        106       1         0         0     
        107       0         1         0     
        107       1         0         0     
        107       1         0         0
```

from the above table what I want to get is if the number of ID is listed more than once and one of the ID or two or all of the ID awaiting = 1? count those ID fulfill the above condition.

and the another query I need is, in which, If the ID listed only and only just once and has awaiting=1;

Please help....

Comment: At least post desired output for both your requested queries based on your sample data

Comment: why you have given me nagative?

Comment: i have just asked, if not clear ask, so that i can clarify more...But why negative?

Comment: Wasn't me, but you're just asking to get it done without telling what you've tried and where you're stuck... Some people don't like this attitude.

Comment: @MR.Test My guess is that someone downvoted you because you didn't show your effort, meaning your version of code with explanation what you expect and what is not working with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) total
  FROM
(
  SELECT id
    FROM Table1
   GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     AND MAX(awaiting = 1) > 0
) q
```

Second

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) total
  FROM
(
  SELECT id
    FROM Table1
   GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
     AND MAX(awaiting = 1) > 0
) q
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c288/5)** demo

Comment: +1 very nice code but removing `q` from the end not work why ?

Comment: @TusharGupta It's not working without `q` because every derived table (subquery) must have an alias. Here is `q` is an alias.

Comment: oh ..!! That means it's working like this `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM q` and `q` is `SELECT id FROM Table1 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1    AND MAX(awaiting = 1) > 0`

Comment: @MR.Test Sure. Take your time.